# To check whether at least one list contains a specific element

Tags: python, list

Could someone please tell me what is the shortest way to write this logic?

I have two lists as `list_one` and `list_two` containing some letters. If none of these two lists contain 'B', I need to print(True). The snippet I have written works, but I am curious to know whether there is a pythonic way to write this instead of  repeating 'B' twice in the same line.

```
    list_one = ['A', 'K', 'L', 'J']
    list_two = ['N', 'M', 'P', 'O']
    
    if 'B' not in list_one and 'B' not in list_two:
        print('True')
```

Thanks in advance and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's a comprehension solution possible here but for 2 lists this is probably the most readable

Comment: I'd keep what you have. Other solutions will involve switching between container types and making copies. That may be acceptable in your case, but I don't think your code's bad enough to warrant the overhead.

Comment: I'll appreciate If you give a thumbs up to my answer @nectarBee :)

Comment: @Sekomer.. Indeed I am happy to do so, but to be honest I do not know how to do that as I am very beginner to stackoverflow. I already marked your solution is useful and accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can do that (even though I think your way is the best):

```
list_one = ['A', 'K', 'L', 'J']
list_two = ['N', 'M', 'P', 'O']
    
if 'B' not in (set(list_one) & set(list_two)):
    print('True')
```

Or:

```
if 'B' not in list_one + list_two:
        print('True')
```

Comment: The list concatenation is elegant, Thank you very much for the prompt reply @Synthase

Comment: No pb! Think about accepting the answer (gray tick top left of the answer which will turn green) is this helped you!

Answer (score 2):

You can try the `all` function if it is more readable for you.

```
list_one = ['A', 'K', 'L', 'J']
list_two = ['N', 'M', 'P', 'O']

print(all('B' not in current_list for current_list in [list_one, list_two]))
```

Comment: all method looks more pythonic. Thanks Albin Paul for the prompt reply.

Answer (score 1):

We have `sets` in Python and they are really fast compared to lists.

Here some features about sets.

- Sets are unordered.
- Set elements are unique.
- Duplicate elements are not allowed in sets.

Therefore you can search the item in a common set.

```
list_one = ['A', 'K', 'L', 'J']
list_two = ['N', 'M', 'P', 'O']

if 'B' not in set(list_one + list_two)
    print('True')
```

Bonus:
You can use `extend` method to speed up list concatenation

```
set( list_one.extend( list_two ))
```

Comment: set union works very well for my application. Thanks Sekomer for the prompt reply.

Comment: I don't think this should be used unless you already have sets though. `set(list_one + list_two)` is doing an iteration of both lists to produce a third copy, then a second iteration to put it into a set, just to avoid a lookup that would, in the worst case, require iterating both lists.

Comment: what is your suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

A different way of doing this is putting all lists in a Pandas DataFrame first:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(list_one, list_two)), columns =['l1', 'l2'])
```

Then you could check easily if the character B is absent by returning a True. The double `.any()` is to check rows and columns:

```
~df.isin(['B']).any().any()
```

Comment: I really appreciate your support Ruthger. This is indeed a useful solution.